# Data for Sentinel-2 L2A product (suddenly) missing in GEE for certain dates

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, sentinel-2

This code returned imagery for two date ranges previously. It suddenly stopped working for the 2nd date range (2018-06 to 2018-09).

I explored setting the cloud cover threshold up to 99 and searching for various dates. No results for the L2A (COPERNICUS/S2_SR) product are returned for any time prior to 2018-12 currently. I have verified that L2A data exists for these dates. The search will return results for the L1C collection (COPERNICUS/S2).

Does anyone have any idea how to again access this data in GEE? Could the part of the collection have been moved?

```
// Get granules from S2 L2A collection w/in study area
var collection_1 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 30))
    .filterDate('2019-12-15', '2020-02-15')
    .filterBounds(studyarea);
    
var collection_2 = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 30))
    .filterDate('2018-06-16', '2018-09-18')
    .filterBounds(studyarea);   
    
print(collection_1); print(collection_2);// generates JSON lists for images
```

Comment: Did switching from S2_SR to S2 solve your problem? I tried that as my solution and am still seeing missing bands of Sentinel data in the United States. Is this common?

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem. You can use a more complete dataset changing:

```
ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR")
```

to the [Sentinel-2 MSI: MultiSpectral Instrument, Level-1C](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2)

```
ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2")
```

In my case it solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Please attach the whole script or at least add your studyarea, otherwise we can't see the region you are working on and the error you are getting.